# React div tag height is zero despite having content,

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

In my Project, I have a  **tag of class Pokedex** that contains some Pokecard components(visible on pic), however, the height of the div tag is always zero, only once I set it in CSS as f.e. height=1000px; the height is properly set. See screens for example
[image: Problem Ilustration]

My code:
CSS:

```
.Pokecard img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.Pokecard p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px;
}

.Pokecard {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 180px;
  min-width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(235, 199, 238);
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
}


.Pokedex {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 95%;
  background-color: cornsilk;
  height: max-content;
}
```

Pokedex component:

```
  myProps = this.props.prokeList;
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Pokedex">
        {[...this.myProps].map((e, index) => {
          return (
            <Pokecard
              key={`pk_${index}`}
              name={e.name}
              id={e.id}
              baseExperience={e.base_experience}
              type={e.type}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Pokecard component

```
class Pokecard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Pokecard">
                <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
                <img 
                src={'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/' +
                `sprites/pokemon/${this.props.id}.png`} alt={this.props.name}/>
                <p>Type: {this.props.type}</p>
                <p>EXP: {this.props.baseExperience}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }    
}
```

Why this happends, I see int the browser inspector that div.Pokedex contains the components but have 0px in height?

**SOLVED**
Reffering to Danko's answer I added this clearfix to my CSS:

```
.Pokedex::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent element has collapsed because children are floats. Use clearfix.